# ¿Cómo editar un archivo python de forma permanente?

Tags: python

soy nuevo y espero no salirme del tema,
lo que deseo saber es si es posible llamar a un archivo de `python` como si fuera un módulo, en este archivo tengo una variable con un listado de correos electrónicos, lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando obtenga otro correo electrónico agregarlo a la lista pero que esta acción quede de forma permanente, espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Orlando lo que pretendes no es imposible pero en condiciones normales no creo que sea la vía de resolver tu problema. ¿Por qué no usas pickle para serializar tu lista por ejemplo?, ¿o guardar las urls en un archivo de texto dejando a tu módulo importado como responsable de manejarlos pero sin alterar su propio código fuente?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que es posible, pero como ya te dijeron no es la forma adecuada, solo a modo de prueba de concepto, lo que preguntas sería más o menos así:

```
import mails

def agregar_mail(fname, correo):

  with open(fname) as fi:
    content = fi.readlines()

  with open(fname, "w") as fo:
    for l in content:
      fo.write(l)
      if l.strip() == "lista_mails = [":
        fo.write('    "{0}",\n'.format(correo))

print("La lista de mails actual es: {0}".format(mails.lista_mails))

mail = input("Ingrese un  correo:")
if mail:
  mails.lista_mails.append(mail)
  agregar_mail(mails.__file__, mail)
```

Y por otro lado en un módulo `mails.py` tendrías algo como esto:

```
lista_mails = [
]
```

Cada vez que ejecutes el primer Script te solicitará un correo que se adicionará a la lista `lista_mails` y se salvara en el módulo `mails.py`. ¿Que problemas puede tener esto?:

- Te exige no editar `mails.py` o hacerlo con mucho cuidado
- No es compatible con la ejecución desde código compilado `.pyc`
- Mucho menos con la distribución ejecutable mediante `pyinstaller` o similares
- Impone una penalidad al tiempo de ejecución al tener que "recompliar" `mails.py` con cada nuevo mail adicionado.
- Puedes ser una víctima muy fácil de inyección de código "malicioso" que podría ser incorporado y ejecutado sin grandes dificultades.

Para persistir datos hay muchísimas formas mejores, las documentación de Python tiene un capítulo especifico y bastante extenso para detallar todas las ya propias del lenguaje ([consultar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html)).

Una de las más clásicas y sencillas es el uso del módulo `pickle` que ya te han mencionado con el cual puedes persistir casi cualquier objeto de Python. En tu caso, una lista (`lista_mails`)

```
import pickle

lista_mails = ["mail1@mail.com","mail2@mail.com"]

# Salvar
with open('lista_mails.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(lista_mails , f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Leer
with open('lista_mails.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    lista_mails = pickle.load(f)
```